# MinkContext - it is not an interface

Tags: symfony, behat, mink

Im trying to integrate behat on symfony 3.4 with the mink component, i already create the following behat.yml:

```
default:
  extensions:
    Behat\Symfony2Extension: ~
    Behat\MinkExtension:
     goutte: ~
     selenium2: ~
     base_url: http://mastersymfony.dev/app_dev.php
```

but when i run behat on console the following error pops:

```
Error: FeatureContext cannot implement Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext - it is not an interface
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should extend `MinkContext` and implement `Context`

```
class FeatureContext extends MinkContext implements Context
{
```